# MYSQL sum totals with coalesce

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a correct working query witch sums the totals per order_id, see below. But how to SUM a total for the whole period of "Excl. BTW en Credit" AND "Totaal BTW excl. Credit"

```
SELECT a.order_id AS "Ordernummer", 
       a.created_at AS "Orderdatum", 
       b.base_grand_total AS "Inclusief BTW", 
       b.base_tax_amount AS "Berekende BTW", 
       c.base_grand_total AS  "Credit-terugbetaald",
       (b.base_grand_total - 
          coalesce(c.base_grand_total, 0)) AS "Incl. BTW en Credit",
       ((b.base_grand_total - 
           coalesce(c.base_grand_total, 0)) - 
           (b.base_tax_amount - 
            coalesce(c.base_tax_amount, 0))) AS "Excl. BTW en Credit",
        (b.base_tax_amount - coalesce(c.base_tax_amount, 0)) AS "Totaal BTW excl. Credit"
FROM `sales_order_item` a 
INNER JOIN sales_invoice b ON a.order_id = b.order_id
LEFT JOIN sales_creditmemo c ON a.order_id = c.order_id
WHERE a.created_at > '2017-01-01'
GROUP BY a.order_id
```

Comment: Very unclear. Your query does a GROUP BY but they arent any aggregate function in the SELECT: Where are the SUMs done?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: There are more rows per order_id, so when i simply remove the GROUP BY (and some Selects) than it counts rows multiple times.

Comment: Provide sample data and desired resuls.

Comment: *"then it counts rows multiple times"*.... yes, that is what JOINs do. Better get used to that pretty quick.

Comment: Your query misues MySQL's nonstandard extension to `GROUP BY`. Please read this. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html  You're definitely in talking donkey territory with this one: it's not astonishing it works badly, it's astonishing it works at all.